# Installation issue in 18.04

Tags: 18.04

HiI'm new to Linux and I like to learn more about Linux, so I  tried to install Ubuntu 118.04. Whenever I install Linux any distro not only Ubuntu even Linux mint, in final stage it showing error message like " you are running out of  Free space 0.0mb available".. I don't know what to do.. please some one help me to solve this issue.. Now I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04 at final stage it showing error in "installer crashed", during detecting hardware process in installation..

Comment: how many GBs is your hard drive?

Comment: ITB hard drive.. I gave erase hard disk and install.. and I allocated 100 gb for root and 4 gb for swap. Remaining free space. I have 8gb of RAM.

Comment: So you partitioned manually? What happens if you just let the installer do whatever it wants? Does it still fail? If yes this may be a hardware problem with your drive.